# Basic Authorization using CURL and Fastbill API

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl, http-headers

i'm having a hard time authorizing a user login since i just dont know the right syntax. I want to modify https://github.com/ZWEISCHNEIDER/fastbill to enable said login API-wise.

The current header bit looks like this and works

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($this->email.':'.$this->apiKey)
                )
            );
```

With this i can connect to the general API and get all the information. In  the documentation of the API it requires me to put the following additional info into the header (left -u line there for better understanding) in order to receive user-bound information only.

```
-u {E-Mail-Address}:{API-Key} \
-H 'X-Username: {User-Emailaddress}'\
-H 'X-Password: {User-Password}' \
```

How do i adapt the 'header' content-string to fit X-Username:$username and X-Password:$pwd in there?

(api doc: https://www.fastbill.com/api/fastbill/en/fundamentals.html#authentification)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok i'm sorry, this did not have anything to do with malformed header requests from my side -- the api simply won't let me access like i planned using a regular api key